# How do I "group" hooks?

Tags: init-file

There are certain things like the display of trailing whitespace, display of buffer boundaries, rainbow-colored delimiters and many more I'd like to enable in most modes or rather, all programming- and text-related ones (because displaying trailing spaces in, say `ediff-mode`, would clash with the major mode) instead of using a globalized minor mode with exception rules. Since most modes are derived from either `prog-mode` or `text-mode`, adding the function in question to both `prog-mode-hook` and `text-mode-hook` does work, however there are enough modes not following this specification, such as `css-mode` or `LaTeX-mode`.

I'd like to define a hook that encompasses all these modes for the time being to only add functions to one hook. Let's call it `non-special-mode-hook` (to distinguish it from `special-mode-hook`). How would I be able to create such a hook that is run for all major modes it is made for?

Comment: You could also [highlight trailing whitespace only in buffers which are visiting a file](https://github.com/pkkm/.emacs.d/blob/cb888c3d2f98212ee528ca4859d410afb9f5612f/conf/view/trailing-whitespace.el).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just group those settings together into a function, and add that function to all of the relevant hook functions:

```
(defun my-non-special-mode-setup ()
  (setq show-trailing-whitespace t)
  ...)
(dolist (hook '(prog-mode-hook text-mode-hook css-mode-hook ...))
  (add-hook hook 'my-non-special-mode-setup))
```

No other way to do this would be more concise: whatever happens, somewhere you're going to have either a whitelist or blacklist of modes. In practice, you'll only find a few modes which need adding to the list, so I'd suggest just keeping things simple.

In my own config, I [use exactly this trick](https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/blob/168cd09e01518cde9af72df09ea54fd396b88b47/lisp/init-lisp.el#L147-L176) to unify the configuration of several lisp-oriented modes.

Comment: Thank you, I think I'll adapt this solution for other useful groups (such as the lispy ones), too.

Comment: That's exactly what I do myself: https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/blob/2a3792dfdcbd8f38b7a28bfe6cc04d7d086e7b61/lisp/init-lisp.el#L160

Comment: Excellent, could you maybe add the URL to your answer? I believe the highlighted snippet not only explains the actual usage very well, but also demonstrates further usage, such as using an Emacs Lisp related "hook" as subset of a bigger "hook" and how one would automatically create hook names from existing major modes with `derived-mode-hook-name`.

Comment: I like this more than mine, just for the `(dolist ...)` vs `(add-hook ...)` <repeat>.  I'd only stick with mine when keeping mode-specific changes separate (file-per-mode, `use-package`, `el-get`).  Both are all-in-one-place solutions, but from different points-of-view.

Comment: Be aware that if you do not provide a non-nil `APPEND` argument to `add-hook` here then the hooks will be invoked in the reverse order from the list order you provide. Nothing wrong with that; just be aware of it, in case the order matters.

Answer (score 5):

You could add a function to `after-change-major-mode-hook`, that checks whether the new mode is an interesting one (possibly through `(not (derived-mode-p 'special-mode))`), and if so runs `non-special-mode-hook`.

Comment: This sounds pretty nifty (once one has figured out all "unspecial" modes since there are a few that just use `fundamental-mode`, but do more than just displaying text), but a bit too magic for my taste. Hence the upvote.

Answer (score 4):

I found myself often doing @sanityinc's pattern of wrapping my settings and minor mode activations in a defun and looping through hooks to call it, but I wanted a cleaner approach so I wrote this macro:

```
(defmacro hook-modes (modes &rest body)
  (declare (indent 1))
  `(--each ,modes
     (add-hook (intern (format "%s-hook" it))
               (lambda () ,@body))))
```

Note: I'm [`dash.el`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) for cleanliness but it could easily be adapted to use `(dolist)`.

Then you can define grouped modes as list variables and use it like so:

```
(defvar progish-modes
  '(prog-mode css-mode sgml-mode))

(hook-modes progish-modes
  (highlight-symbol-mode)
  (highlight-symbol-nav-mode))
```

Comment: Note that here you can use `derived-mode-hook-name` to get the name of a mode's hook variable, thereby avoiding the `intern` trick.

Comment: @sanityinc TIL `derived-mode-hook-name`. nice tip!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than define a new hook that works for all these *non-derived* modes you can do the following.

```
(defun run-my-hooks ()
  "Run all the following functions in the hook"
  (smartparens-mode 1)
  (whitespace-mode 1)
  (my-needed-mode 1)
  ...)

(add-hook 'specific-mode-hook 'run-my-hooks)
(add-hook 'another-mode-hook 'run-my-hooks)
```

You'll still need to add it to all the modes, but by defining your function to include all the modes you will only have to change one definition when adding/removing addtional features.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on @legoscia's answer with some code, I solved the same problem as follows. Note the addition of a check for `fundamental-mode`, since otherwise the hook will trigger on mini-buffers as well.

```lisp
(defcustom non-special-mode-hook nil
  "Hook run when entering non-special modes (catches 'prog-mode', 'text-mode', and 'fundamental-mode')."
  :type 'hook)

(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook
          (lambda () "Trigger non-special-mode hooks that are also fundamental, so don't catch minibuffers."
            (when (and (not (derived-mode-p 'special-mode))
                       (derived-mode-p 'fundamental-mode))
              (run-hooks 'non-special-mode-hook))))
```

From there you can hook into `'non-special-mode-hook` like normal, or change the predicates in the `when` call to narrow the scope of which modes trigger the hook.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my overkill:

```
(defun my/hooks-hooks (hook-or-hooks mode-or-modes)
       (if (listp hook-or-hooks)
           (dolist (hook hook-or-hooks)
             (add-hook hook mode-or-modes))
         (if (listp mode-or-modes)
             (dolist (hook hook-or-hooks)
             (add-hook hook mode-or-modes))
           ;; else
           (throw 'error "my/hooks-hooks")
           )))
(my/hooks-hooks 'python-mode-hook '('ECFPAW/prettify-symbols-pack/asterik-to-multiplication
                                    'ECFPAW/prettify-symbols-pack/in-equalities
                                    'ECFPAW/prettify-symbols-pack/lambda
                                    'ECFPAW/prettify-symbols-pack/pointers))
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can try this:

```
(setq lisp-dialects-mode-hook '(lisp-mode-hook
                            lisp-interaction-mode-hook
                            emacs-lisp-mode-hook
                            ;; common-lisp-mode-hook
                            scheme-mode-hook
                            clojure-mode-hook
                            cider-repl-mode-hook
                            ))

(add-hook 'lisp-dialects-mode-hook 'func)
```