# mutilpe add-hook merge to one?

Tags: hooks

On my config i have too many `add-hook`,Is there any way to merge them and make them more beautiful.

```
  (add-hook 'go-mode-hook #'my-go-project-setup)
  (add-hook 'go-mode-hook #'lsp-deferred)
  (add-hook 'go-mode-hook #'lsp-go-install-save-hooks)
  (add-hook 'go-mode-hook #'rainbow-delimiters-mode)
  (add-hook 'go-mode-hook #'galaxy/go-defun-setup)
```

maybe write a macro is best? then it will like this? how to write this macro or other best way?

```
(add-hook-x 'go-mode-hook #'lsp-deferred
                          #'lsp-go-instal-save-hooks
                          ...)
```

Answer (score 5):

No need for a macro, all you need is a function doing a loop:

```
(defun add-hook-x (hook &rest functions)
  (dolist (function functions)
    (add-hook hook function)))
```

There isn't really a need for this either once you realize that you can bundle all these functions added to the hook into a single function:

```
(defun my-go-mode-setup ()
  (my-go-project-setup)
  (lsp-deferred)
  (lsp-go-install-save-hooks)
  (rainbow-delimiters-mode)
  (galaxy/go-defun-setup))

(add-hook 'go-mode-hook #'my-go-mode-setup)
```

For the opposite case where you want to add a single function to many hooks you might find this question of mine useful: [How do I "group" hooks?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/501/how-do-i-group-hooks)

Comment: i know  write them to a function , but it looks like ugly..thanks.